# Simple way to to authorize access to my API

Tags: security, amazon-web-services, oauth

I'm working at a very early stage company, with two other people. The company provides analytics for enterprise, hosted in AWS. We have an internal api for querying data for testing our algorithms, and I am trying to figure out the best way to authorize access to it. We are 6+ months from launching, and these endpoints would not be offered to customers, but I want to at least limit access to our data so that just knowing our endpoints does not give you access. So far we have been using IP authorization with AWS, but since we have been traveling a bit, it has become less practical. I was thinking of moving us to a home-brewed key model, where I would give each of the devs a 160 bit key, and have them include it for any api calls. I realize it is not a robust long-term solution, but is there anything inherently dangerous about it that I am missing? Obviously some type of OAuth in the 6 month horizon makes sense, but for now I want to keep it simple. Any suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Basic Authentication](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2617) + HTTPS is the simplest way.

Generate a pair of API key and API secret for your client application. Your client application is supposed to include `Authorization` HTTP header (which is properly formatted for Basic Authentication) when accessing your protected APIs.